# Unable to detrmine if a test failed in an after hook

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests

I try to do some extra stuff when a test fails.

This is the failing test:

```
it 'fails' do
  expect(1213).to eq('123456')
end
```

Following code is added to the spec_helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:each) do |example|
    if example.exception
      puts 'Do something'
    end
  end
```

Results in following output:

> expected: "123456"
>        got: "1213"
>   (compared using ==)
>
> 1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed
>
> Finished in 2 seconds

The exception on example stays nil, i do not understand wy. Is there another way to achieve extra code after a failing test?

Comment: Try using `example.execution_result.status = ...` instead of `example.exception`

Comment: I tried it but the value is always null.

Comment: Check this comment https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2011#issuecomment-114669886 - I think it's the answer (and there is a solution too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer (and an idea of the solution too) https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2011#issuecomment-114669886:

> Anyhow, the status is not set until AFTER the after hooks run. That is intentional because the after hook is itself part of the example, and if an exception occurs in the after hook we'll set the status of the example to :failed. after hooks are great for cleanup/teardown logic but isn't intended for observing the status of examples. Instead, I recommend you use a formatter for that...

Answer (score 0):

The code should work perfectly, you should see "Do something" right before the "F" get printed on STDOUT, something like this:

```
Randomized with seed 3598
Do something
F

Failures:

  1) Blah#blah fails
     Failure/Error: expect(1213).to eq('123456')

       expected: "123456"
            got: 1213

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/index_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01617 seconds (files took 0.09568 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed
```

Also note which rspec version you are using, your test report looks different from mine. Mine is on v3.8